# What does this syntax in c++ means?

Tags: c++

I found a code from someone to solve a code question, but I really don't understand this line
`if(!(dp[i] = dp[i + 1] || str[i] != str[j]) && (e - s) <= (j - i))`, and what the array "dp" really do?  What does `dp[i] = dp[i+1]` mean? Isn't it assigning `dp[i+1]` to `dp[i]`??? Here is the code.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string str) {
        const int n = str.size();
        if(n < 2) return str;
        int s = 0, e = 0;
        int dp[n] = {0, };
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i){
                if(!(dp[i] = dp[i + 1] || str[i] != str[j]) && (e - s) <= (j - i)) 
                    s = i, e = j;
            }
        }
        return str.substr(s, e - s + 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: I think it will be helpful to you in the long run to understand the basics of the language from a [good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Getting answers to the specific questions you ask will only benefit you in the short term.

Comment: I assume that `=` is meant to be a `==`

Comment: @HongOoi How can you know whether or not that is the intention of the original creator of the code?

Comment: anthony, the `dp` array is not syntax but instead the calculation storage for a dynamic programming solution to this presumably competitive programming problem. This is not a programming problem, so it doesn't really belong on stackoverflow. Read more about dp here: https://blog.usejournal.com/top-50-dynamic-programming-practice-problems-4208fed71aa3

Comment: Note `int dp[n] = {0, };` is not standard C++ since `n` is not a constant expression (its value is not known at compile time). The code is relying on a language extension provided by some compilers.

Answer (score 3):

> What does dp[i] = dp[i+1] mean? Isn't it assigning dp[i+1] to dp[i]

Not exactly! As the `||` operator has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `=` operator, the assignment is actually equivalent to this:

```cpp
dp[i] = ( dp[i+1] || (str[i] != str[j]) );
```

But all expressions in `C++` have a *value* as well as an *effect*. In the case of an assignment, like the one here, the *value* of the expression is the same as the value that is ultimately assigned (to the LHS). So, here, the value of the expression will be equal to the value of `dp[i + 1]` logically ORed with the result of the `str[i] != str[j]` comparison. If the `i` and `j` elements are *not* equal, then `dp[i]` will be given the value of `1`; if they *are* the same, it will be given the value of `dp[i+1]`.

The use of this expression *inside* a logical test condition achieves two things:

- First, it accomplishes the assignment (as expected)
- Second, it checks whether or not the assigned value is non-zero ("true").

The second point is used to further evaluate the entire `if` statement.

As this is the first expression to be evaluated, the code could be written more clearly (though less succinctly) as follows:

```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i){
        dp[i] = dp[i + 1] || (str[i] != str[j]); // Do the assignment...
        if((dp[i] == 0) && (e - s) <= (j - i))  // ... then test dp[i]
            s = i, e = j;
    }
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: `=` has lower precedence than `||`.

Comment: yeah, thank you two! I know what's wrong now! The question of dp array is also solved since I get it after I read through all code. Thanks @Adrian Mole.